# Combine Shiro filters with Java Annotations in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, shiro

I am configuring Shiro in Java. I want to secure REST API with it. I use token based authentication. I configure ShiroFilterFactoryBean as below:

```
@Bean
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterBean() {
    ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();

    HashMap<String, String> definitionMap = Maps.newHashMap();
    definitionMap.put("/api/auth", "anon");
    definitionMap.put("/api/**", "noSessionCreation, authc");
    shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(definitionMap);

    HashMap<String, Filter> filters = Maps.newHashMap();
    filters.put("authc", new RestTokenAuthenticatingFilter());
    shiroFilter.setFilters(filters);

    shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager());
    return shiroFilter;
}
```

Then I have RestController as follow:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Inject
    RestService restService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity login(@RequestBody LoginDto loginDto) {
        String restToken = // ... create token
        return new ResponseEntity<>(restToken, HttpStatus.OK);
    }    

    @RequestMapping("/secure")
    @RequiresAuthentication
    public String secure() {
        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        return "Should be 'true' == " + subject.isAuthenticated() + " ** " + subject.getPrincipal();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/insecure")
    public String insecure() {
        return "You dont have to be authenticated";
    }
}
```

How can I force this line

```
filters.put("authc", new RestTokenAuthenticatingFilter());
```

to be applied only to methods annotated with @RequiresAuthentication (and others) from Shiro?

Why I want to do that? For example I want to have something like that

- `GET /api/cars` to be allowed for all users
- `POST /api/cars` to be allowed only for authenticated users

I am not able to achieve that when I define filters in ShiroFilterFactoryBean.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I've stucked with this problem too

Comment: Unfortunately not